# How do you auto format code in Android Studio on save for Flutter?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

Is there any way to auto-formatcode in Android Studio on save for Flutter?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Open **Settings**
2. Go to **Languages & Frameworks**
3. Select **Flutter**
4. Tick **Format code on save**

[image: res]

Answer (score 2):

Flutter How to enable auto-format on "`save`" in android studio
on macOS, the initial step is slightly different

**AndroidStudio->Prefrences->Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter and check Format code on save.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio Flamingo 2022.
You can do it in two ways:
First, open your project, then

```
File -> settings -> under Languages & Frameworks -> select Flutter or Dart -> 
Select format code on save
```

Also, can be done via:

```
Tools -> Actions on Save -> Reformat code
```